# Unbalanced quotes exception when executing Maven exec plugin in Bamboo plan

Tags: java, maven, bamboo, exec-maven-plugin

So I got this annoying exception in one of my Bamboo plans while I try to execute Maven exec plugin: `Unbalanced quotes "-Dargument=value`.

The command I'm trying to run is:

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.args="-Dargument=value"
```

The same command works just fine when I execute it in my command line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple. Thanks to a comment on [this Jira ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-9234)
I found that the correct way to pass such arguments is:

```
mvn exec:exec "-Dexec.args=-Dargument=value"
```

instead of:

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.args="-Dargument=value"
```

Comment: Quite annoying bug".
I would have thought that bamboo would be able to pass commands with quotes without any issues.